# Custom Post Types and Broken Permalinks

Tags: posts, permalinks, customization

The permalinks on my website breaks frequently. I found out that it's being caused by a plugin I created.

The plugin basically creates a custom post type with custom fields and stores in the wp-posts and wp-post-meta tables.

I heard that it's occurring because I'm saving them to the wp-post table. So how do I save them to a different table? And how do I fetch them from that table. I can do it by the conventional PHP and MySQL ways but I want to take advantage of the WordPress functions. Can this be done?

Code to create custom post type and taxonomy

```
function dwwp_register_post_type(){

    $singular = 'Speaker';
    $plural = 'Speakers';

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => $plural,
        'singular_name'         => $singular,
        'add_name'              => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New '.$singular,
        'edit'                  => 'Edit',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit '.$singular,
        'new_item'              => 'New '.$singular,
        'view'                  => 'View '.$singular,
        'view_item'             => 'View '.$singular,
        'search_term'           => 'Search '.$plural,
        'parent'                => 'Parent '.$singular,
        'not_found'             => 'No '.$plural.' Found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No '.$plural.' in Trash',
    );


    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'menu_position'         => 6,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-businessman',
        'can_export'            => true,
        'delete_with_user'      => false,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'          => true,
        'rewrite'               => array(
                                    'slug' => 'speakers',
                                    'with_front' => true,
                                    'pages' => true,
                                    'feeds' => true,
                                ),
        'supports'              => array(
                                    'title',
                                    //'editor',
                                    //'author',
                                    //'custom-fields',
                                    'thumbnail'
                                )
        );

    register_post_type('speakers', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'dwwp_register_post_type');

function dwwp_register_taxonomy(){

    $plural = 'Years';
    $singular = 'Year';

    $labels = array(
        'name' => $plural,
        'singular_name' => $singular,
        'search_items' => 'Search '.$plural,
        'popular_items' => 'Popular '.$plural,
        'all_items' => 'All '.$plural,
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => 'Edit '.$singular,
        'update_item' => 'Update '.$singular,
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New '.$singular,
        'new_item_name' => 'New '.$singular.' Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate '.$plural.' with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or Remove '.$plural,
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used '.$plural,
        'not_found' => 'No '.$plural.' found',
        'menu_name' => $plural,
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'year'
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy('year', 'speakers', $args);

}
add_action('init', 'dwwp_register_taxonomy');
```

Now I created 3 custom fields for all the speakers: Short description, Full Description and the Year is the custom taxonomy.
Code to store in Database From Input Fields

```
function dwwp_add_custom_metabox(){
    add_meta_box('dwwp_meta', 'Speakers Description', 'dwwp_meta_callback', 'speakers', 'normal', 'core');
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'dwwp_add_custom_metabox');

function dwwp_meta_callback( $post ){

    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'dwwp_speakers_nonce');
    $dwwp_stored_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
    ?>
    <div class="meta-th">
        <div class="meta-th">
            <span>Short Description</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-editor"></div>
            <?php
            $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'short-description', true);
            $editor = 'short-description';
            $settings = array(
                'textarea_rows' => 5,

            );
            wp_editor($content, $editor, $settings);
            ?>
    </div>
    <div class="meta-th">
        <div class="meta-th">
            <span>Long Description</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-editor"></div>
            <?php
            $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'long-description', true);
            $editor = 'long-description';
            $settings = array(
                'textarea_rows' => 10,

            );
            wp_editor($content, $editor, $settings);
            ?>
    </div>

<?php }

function dwwp_meta_save($post_id){
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave($post_id);
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision($post_id);
    $is_valid_nonce = (isset($_POST['dwwp_speakers_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['dwwp_speakers_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) ? 'true' : 'false' ;

    if ($is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce){
        return;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['short-description'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'short-description', sanitize_text_field($_POST['short-description']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['long-description'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'long-description', sanitize_text_field($_POST['long-description']));
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'dwwp_meta_save');
```

Then to display the speakers in a grid and have a popup to display their details in other places.
Code to create a shortcode to display in other places

```
<?php

/*
==============================================
Display the speakers in a grid system
==============================================
*/

function speakers_grid_display($atts, $content = null){

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'years' => array('2018', '2017', '2016')
        ), $atts
    );

    $return_args[] = '<div id="section3">
                        <div class="animation-element slide slide-left testimonial">
                            <div class="row text-center">
                                <h1 class="heading-1">Speakers</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container gal-container">';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'speakers',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'year',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => $atts['years']
            ),
        ),
    );

    $speakers_list = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($speakers_list->have_posts()):
        while ($speakers_list->have_posts()): $speakers_list->the_post();

            $return_args[] = '<div class="gal-item show_info">
                                <div class="box" style="background-image: url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()).')">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <span class="name">'.get_the_title().'</span>
                                            <br />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';

        endwhile;
    endif;

    $return_args[] = '</div></div>';

    $args = join($return_args);
    return $args;
}
add_shortcode('speakers-grid-display', 'speakers_grid_display');

/*
=============================================================
Display speakers with pop ups
=============================================================
*/

function speakers_popup($atts, $content = null){

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'years' => array('2018', '2017', '2016')
        ), $atts
    );

    $return_args[] = '<div id="section3">
                        <div class="animation-element slide slide-left testimonial">
                            <div class="row text-center">
                                <h1 class="heading-1">Speakers</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container gal-container">';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'speakers',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'year',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => $atts['years']
            ),
        ),
    );

    $speakers_list = new WP_Query($args);

    $i = 1;

    if ($speakers_list->have_posts()):
        while ($speakers_list->have_posts()): $speakers_list->the_post();

            $return_args[] = '<a href="#" data-target="#div'.$i.'" class="gal-item show_info">
                                <div class="box" style="background-image: url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()).')">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <span class="name">'.get_the_title().'</span>
                                            <br />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>';

            $i++;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    $return_args[] = '</div></div>';

    $speakers_list = new WP_Query($args);

    $i = 1;

    if ($speakers_list->have_posts()):
        while ($speakers_list->have_posts()): $speakers_list->the_post();
            $return_args[] = '<div id="div'.$i.'" class="show_speakers_info" style="display:none;">
                                <div class="profile-header-container">
                                    <div class="profile-header-img">
                                        <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()).'" />
                                        <!-- badge -->
                                        <div class="profile-heading">
                                            <h3 class="heading-2">'.get_the_title().'</h3>
                                            <em>'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "short-description", true).'</em>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-justify">
                                    '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "long-description", true).'
                                </div>
                            </div>';

            $i++;

        endwhile;
    endif;

    $return_args = join($return_args);

    return $return_args;




}
add_shortcode('speakers-popup', 'speakers_popup');
```

And then I created another page to just reorder the list of the speakers

```
<?php
//Add submenu
function dwwp_add_submenu_page(){
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=speakers',
        'Reorder Speakers',
        'Reorder Speakers',
        'manage_options',
        'reorder_speakers',
        'reorder_callback'
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'dwwp_add_submenu_page');


//Reorder speakers
function reorder_callback(){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'speakers',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false,
        'post_per_page' => 50
    );

    $speakers_list = new WP_Query($args);?>

    <div id="speakers-sort" class="sort">
        <div id="icon-job-admin" class="icon32"><br/></div>
        <h2>Reorder Speakers
        <img src = "<?php echo esc_url(admin_url() .'/images/loading.gif'); ?>"  alt="loading.gif" id="loading-animation" ></h2>

        <?php
        if ($speakers_list->have_posts()): ?>
        <ul id="custom-type-list">
            <?php 
            while ($speakers_list->have_posts()): $speakers_list->the_post();
            ?>
            <li id="<?php the_id(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p>No Speakers</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>


<?php
}

function dwwp_save_reorder(){

    if (!check_ajax_referer('wp-speakers-order', 'security')){
        return wp_send_json_error('Invalid Nonce');
    }

    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')){
        return wp_send_json_error( 'You are not allowed to do this.' );
    }

    $order = $_POST['order'];
    $count = 0;
    foreach( $order as $item_id ){

        $post = array(
            'ID' => (int)$item_id,
            'menu_order' => $count
        );
        wp_update_post($post);
        $count++;
    }

    wp_send_json_success('Post Saved.');

}
add_action('wp_ajax_save_post', 'dwwp_save_reorder');
```

And then finally in the index page, the code is

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Speakers
Plugin URI: Speakers
Author: Speakers
Version: 1.0.0
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')){
    exit;
}

require ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'speakers_custom_post_type.php' );
require ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'speakers_custom_meta_box.php' );
require ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'speakers_reorder_submenu.php' );
require ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'speakers_shortcode.php');

function dwwp_admin_enqueue_scripts(){
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if ($typenow == 'speakers'){
        wp_enqueue_style('dwwp-admin-css', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('dwwp-admin-js', plugins_url('js/style.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' , 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ), '1.0.0', true);
    }

    if (($pagenow == 'post.php' || $pagenow == 'post-new.php') && $typenow == 'speakers'){
        wp_enqueue_style('dwwp-admin-css', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('dwwp-admin-js', plugins_url('js/reorder.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' , 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ), '1.0.0', true);
    }

    if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $typenow == 'speakers'){
        wp_enqueue_script('dwwp-reorder-admin-js', plugins_url('js/reorder.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' , 'jquery-ui-sortable' ), '1.0.0', true);
        wp_localize_script('dwwp-reorder-admin-js', 'WP_SPEAKERS_LISTING', array(
            'security' => wp_create_nonce('wp-speakers-order'),
            'success' => __('Speakers sort order has been saved.'),
            'failure' => __('There was an error saving the sort order, or you do not have priviledges')
        ));
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'dwwp_admin_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: This theory that it's because you're saving them to the posts table makes no sense, and is a complete red herring. I also see no code in your answer, nor do I see what this plugin is meant to do. Can you explain what your plugin does in a non-technical manner, followed by how it does it? Edit your question with the info, don't post it as a comment. Also, are you flushing rewrite rules, and if so, where and when do you do so?

Comment: I have added the code and the working. Please have a look. Also, I have no idea about flushing rewrite rules.

Comment: you need to [flush rewrites on plugin activation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Examples).

Comment: @Milo you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Examples) on plugin activation for your custom post type to begin working.

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_flush_rewrites' );
function myplugin_flush_rewrites() {
    // call your CPT registration function here
    // (it should also be hooked into 'init')
    dwwp_register_post_type();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

You may have noticed it randomly working without having to do this, if some other code flushed rules, such as when you visit the Settings > Permalinks admin page.